# Is it possible to write Kindle ebook with LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, adobe, kindle

I intend to self-publish a book on the Kindle platform.

Adobe PDF is one of the supported formats in which you can submit your book.

Since I'm using Ubuntu, is it possible for me to use LibreOffice and convert my LO file to Adobe PDF?

Comment: Why are you using LO for docx files ? You can export as a PDF. If your file is written in MS Word (docx) export it from word. If it is written in LO, export it from LO. Although you can read docx on LO, there may be formatting differences between LO and MS Word. For your purpose, I highly advise you use on or the other, but not both.

Comment: You can consider publishing as mobi file - native Kindle ebook format. You can easily create mobi from docx via Calibre.

Comment: @iacobus  I made a mistake - LO is what I intended

Comment: As a side note: There are also options to export ODTs to ePub files, which are also supported by Kindle: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/EPUB/Converting_ODF_to_EPUB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly it is possible. Just write your book in LibreOffice Writer, save it, and export it to PDF using the built-in export function, which even has its own button.

Comment: If the docx document was origionally written in word, there may be significant formatting differences.

Comment: I admit there may be formatting issues. Amazon provide a free [booklet](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B007URVZJ6) on how to format the document, using MS Word 2010.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Sorry, I made a mistake - LO is what I intended

Answer (score 0):

PDF is not a good choice for a kindle ebook. It's perfect for a print version, but for ebooks you'll better take the rtf approach.